# error when using KFold() and roc_auc metric

Tags: scikit-learn, cross-validation

why `cross_val_score(pipe,X,y,scoring="roc_auc",cv=StratifiedKFold())` works just fine and when using KFold() like `cross_val_score(pipe,X,y,scoring="roc_auc",cv=KFold())`  error occurs saying

> Only one class present in y_true. ROC AUC score is not defined in
> that case

.

Comment: This can happen if your actual labels `y_true` are all of the same class. For example, suppose all the labels in `y_true` are positives (=1), then false positives (predicted value 1, true value 0) and true negatives (predicted value 0, true value 0) are not defined. Metrics that depend on using FP/TN are undefined too. Therefore you need to ensure that you have representation of both/all true classes in `y_true`, for example by using `StratifiedKFold` strategy . See also: https://stackoverflow.com/a/45139405/490648

Answer (score 1):

The [StratifiedKFold](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.model_selection.StratifiedKFold.html), as the name suggests, yields folds whose classes are inherently balanced. And so if your `y` contains at least two classes you won't get any error. Otherwise, [KFold](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.model_selection.StratifiedKFold.html) just splits the data as it is presented so you may get a fold in which only one class is present thus raising the error.

Anyway, I believe the issue is that you forgot to set `shuffle=True` when instantiating `KFold` (the same for the stratified version.)

If you still run into the same error, then you probably have *very unbalanced classes* and so for k-fold is very unlucky to yield a fold that presents both classes. In such case, just use the stratified k-fold, or reduce the `n_splits` which defaults to 5.